# Using Entity framework generic repository with web api and many to many relationships

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In my Web API application I implemented the generic repository pattern as described in this [post](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/generic-repository-pattern-entity-framework-asp-net-mvc-and-unit-testing-triangle).
So now whenever I create a Crud Api controller I use a service that uses a repository to talk to database.

Lets say I have those two entity models

```
public class Student
{
    public Student() 
    {
        this.Courses = new HashSet<Course>();
    }

    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
     public Course()
     {
        this.Students = new HashSet<Student>();
     }
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public string CourseName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

And my Controllers and service classes are as follows

```
public class StudentsController 
{
    private StudentsService studentService;

   // CRUD Api Methods...
}

public class StudentService
{
    private StudentsRepository studentsRepo;

   // CRUD Api Methods...
}
```

In the front end whenever I send a post request to the api like:

```
/api/Students : Post
{
  "id": 9999,
   "studentName":"string",
   "Courses":[
    {
      "id":13
    }, 
    {
      "id":25
    }]
}
```

For some strange reason the repository tries to create those new two courses even thought they exists in the database and it fails.
If I change the relationship to one to many and change the Post to send only one course id like this

```
/api/Students : Post
{
  "id": 9999,
   "studentName":"string",
    "CourseId":13
}
```

The EF saves the changes successfully.

I managed to make this work by having both repositories instantiated in my 
Students service and then grab all the ids from the incoming Student model
make a call to the courseRepo to fetch all the Courses and override the incoming
Student.Courses with the ones I fetched from the database.

This works but it seems like a bad practice to me. I thought that the whole purpose of doing this service-repository was to have a clean backend , something like MicroServices architecture.

Comment: This generic repository pattern implementation is quite naïve, specifically the `Edit` method will not work in any EF version. Detached related entities require special attention.

Comment: So, you fixed this, but you don't like your fix?  If your service was fixed by changing the implementation without affecting the service interface, I'd say you just realized the promise of component-oriented architecture and dependency injection (assuming your using that) and you should walk away happy.  The "cleanliness" of the architecture comes in just like this: it doesn't promise that there won't be some ugliness on the backend (and there will *always* be ugliness with object graph merging in EF) just that the ugliness is contained, both discreetly and discretely.

Comment: Yes I use dependency injection and no I didn't change the interface I just have to inject both repositories into my service instead of one.